# How to animate VertexWeightProximity effect with Remesh modifier active

Tags: modifiers, vertex-groups, vertex-weights, geometry-nodes, remesh

What I'm trying to do in blender 2.93.1: Animate a VertexWeightProximity effect (geometry nodes distributed/instanced cubes on mesh going away as empty gets near) while also animating the main mesh becoming less blocky (via animating remesh octree depth).

Problem: The Remesh modifier won't allow the VertexWeightProximity effect to happen.

[image: General Setup with Remesh enabled and proximity not working]

When the Remesh modifier is disabled the proximity effect works as expected, but this won't allow me to animate the remesh change happening at the same time.
[image: General Setup with Remesh disabled and proximity effect working]

I've tried changing the modifier order and other basic stuff (I'm fairly inexperienced with Blender) but nothing seems to work. Anyone have a suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Remesh modifier destroys vertex groups on the mesh, rendering the Vertex Weight Proximity modifier useless in that case. Thankfully there is a built-in [Attribute Proximity](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_proximity.html) node that you can use in the GN modifier.

It only works with Geometry though, so instead of an Empty object, you'll have to use a small mesh object, like a scaled down cube. Make sure to set the node to "Relative" or else it won't react when you move the falloff object.

[image]

Place the GN modifier after the remesh :

[image]

Result :

[image]

Comment: You did not hide the original Suzanne object?!I am a bit disappointed….but…ok…+1

Comment: @Chris Ups... Consider that as a backstage tour :)

Comment: This is good, but if they wanted to use the empty, they could also use a vertex weight edit modifier to assign all remeshed vertices to the proximity VG, between remeshing and checking prox.

Comment: @Nathan In my experience the VW proximity modifier doesn't work if the mesh doesn't contain already initialized weights... It may be a bug but I never bothered bringing it up to see if it's a feature ^^

Comment: I'll show you how to re-initialize weights with vertex weight edit below.

Comment: Thank you Gorgious for this easy solution! It worked perfectly and I was able to easily adjust falloff with an Attribute Color Ramp. I really appreciate your time and everyone's input.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Gorgious, remesh destroys the existing groups.  (There are a number of other situations that do this too; booleans are a good example.)

But for prox, you don't need any particular weights, you just need the weights to exist, and you can initialize them with a vertex weight edit modifier, after the remesh:

[image]

Notice what the vertex weight edit is doing.  First, I'm using a custom curve that just assigns *everything* to my proximity group.  Second, I'm enabling "Group Add" which will add vertices to that group, even if they weren't in that group.  By doing this, I can assign all generated vertices to this group, which then lets me run a proximity on it, which then lets me run geo nodes on it.

There's nothing wrong with what Gorgious is offering; this is just an alternative.

Comment: Thank you Nathan for an alternate solution. I haven't tried it out yet as the marked solution above was a quick solid fix - but I'll try this one out for fun when I have time.

Comment: Oh, nice ! Thanks for the explanation :)